# In Elm, how to access a field by string?

Tags: javascript, elm

in JavaScript we can do obj['name'], is there something similar in Elm?

What I'm trying to do is to create a function to sort a list when user clicks on the column header, so my sort function will take a string or a (.) function to indicate which field to sort by. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Yes, pass it a a function not a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use string to access record field because Elm compiler won't be able to find out if your code is correct. You should create your own function which will map your column name to possible field names and then use it with core [List.sortBy](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/List#sortBy):

```
type alias User = { name : String, height: Int }

sort : String -> List User -> List User
sort column rows = 
    case column of
        "name" -> List.sortBy .name rows
        "height" -> List.sortBy .height rows
        _ -> rows
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but it seems we have to handle each field individually. is it possible to send ".name" or ".height" as a function into the sort function instead of sending the string?

Comment: Yes, the best way would be to avoid passing strings and just use field access function in your onClick handler which is triggered when a user is changing sort column.

Comment: I tried "sort1 f rows = List.sortBy f rows", then I can call "sort1 .height users". It works great, but how do I type that function, like "sort1 : (User -> comparable) -> List User -> List User"?

Comment: `sort1 f rows = List.sorBy f rows` doesn't make too much sens. `sort1` is doing exactly the same what `List.sortBy`.

Comment: That annotation should work. It's the same as `List.sortBy` but you've repleced general `a` type with specific `User`: `sortBy : (a -> comparable) -> List a -> List a`

Comment: good point, I don't even need to create any function to do it, thanks